# linux + how to know if server is boot from san or have local disk

Tags: linux, rhel, disk

we have redhat servers ,

how to know if linux physical server is boot from SAN or have local disk?

which files can indicates this?

I ask because we need to do some configuration only on the servers that boot from SAN

Answer (score 1):

To find which drive is your boot device.

```
lsbk | grep /boot
```

Then when you know the name of your device

```
ls -l /sys/block/sda
```

It wil return something like:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar 30 09:27 /sys/block/sda -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sda
```

Where **00:10.0** is your device ID.
And now when you know which device you are exactly looking for you kan issue:

```
lspci | grep "00:10.0"
```

If you cant find it it means that device is not attached locally. I think it's obvious that you can easily script this process.

Comment: we cant use this command because yum not find this command in our repositories

Comment: ls -l /sys/block/sda 
To find device symlinks and where they point to. You will get something like:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar 30 09:27 /sys/block/sda -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sda

And with lspci you can examin if its attached locally.  Just serch for itst id.

Comment: So to recap: First lsblk to find on which drive is your /boot. Then ls -l /sys/block/yourbootdrive (in my case it was sda) Then you extract your device id in my case it was pci:0000:00:10 Then you look for your id in lspci to know if its phisically attached to the server you examine. Tell me if it helped so i could edit my answer.